# External Hard-Drive Not Showing Up

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

My "WD My Passport Ultra" (2 TB) isn't showing up whenever I plug it in. My case seems to be slightly different than all the other cases posted on this site:

**What's going on:**

- The unit is getting power
- Light blinks at first then after ~3 seconds stays on (normal behavior)
- Disk inside is spinning
- Device isn't showing in "This PC" folder
- Can't find in Device Manager or Disk Management
- Doesn't matter which USB port it is plugged into. I can confirm that all USB ports are working.

**What happened:** Cord got knocked out while Windows 10 was running its usb fixing utility.

I have tools to repair corrupted partitions and even software to recover lost data. But I need it to actually show up on the computer before I can run any of those.

**Any help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Have you tried a different USB Port usually a good start, could be some damage from when the cord was pulled out.

Comment: I have, and no matter which port it still won't show up.

Comment: Have you tried it in safe mode?

Comment: Have you restarted your machine, stupid thing i know but sometimes device manager likes to throw a hissy fit

Comment: I haven't tried safe mode or restarting yet.

Comment: ... Well I am now ashamed to say that I work in IT. @Englishman Please submit your comment as an answer. That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you restarted your machine, stupid thing i know but sometimes device manager likes to throw a hissy fit

Answer (score 2):

I would also try loading it in a Linux box or liveCD. If you plug it in and it shows up and it will let you mount it, then you know that it is just windows being a jerk and your drive is fine.

If you can mount it try running fsck /mnt/"your-drive" and see if that helps. Then try using it in windows again. Just a suggestion.

Comment: +1 This is what I normally do but I haven't had a chance yet.